# Count the occurrences of bigrams in string and save them into a dictionary

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I code in Python, and I have a string which I want to count the number of occurrences of bigrams in that string. What I mean by that, is that for example I have the string `"test string"` and I would like to iterate through that string in sub-strings of size 2 and create a dictionary of each bigram and the number of its occurrences in the original string.
Thus, I would like to get an output of the form `{te: 1, es : 1, st: 2, ...}`.

Could you help me to get this started?
Best regards!

Comment: Please share the code [mre] you did and explain what problem it has.

Comment: Minor nit: a tuple in Python is a immutable sequence of zero or more items.  It doesn't mean a pair.

Comment: @Jonas I think you meant something like a `bigram` (which is a `n-gram for n = 2`), from your example output at least.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski@hitter ah I see. I only know this term from math :D. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3):

Given

```
s = "test string"
```

do

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(map(''.join, zip(s, s[1:])))
```

or

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(s[i:i+2] for i in range(len(s)-1))
```

The result of either is

```
Counter({'st': 2, 'te': 1, 'es': 1, 't ': 1, ' s': 1, 'tr': 1, 'ri': 1, 'in': 1, 'ng': 1})
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 1):

As a side note, you're looking for [bigrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bigram). For bigger scale – there's robust implementations in different machine-learning/NLP kits.

As an ad-hoc solution, problem should be decomposed to

1. Iterate over "current and next elements" in sequence
2. Count unique pairs.

---

Solution for problem #1 is `pairwise` from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)

Solution for problem #2 is [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

---

Putting all together is

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return zip(a, b)

Counter(pairwise('test string'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is simple and easy to do, and there is no need to `import` any library.

Firstly we remove all white-space from the string using `join()`.
Then we construct a `list` containing all sub-strings with a step of `2`.
Finally we construct and `print()` the `dictionary` which has all sub-strings as  keys and their respective occurrences in the original string as values.

```
substr = [] # Initialize empty list that contains all substrings.
step = 2 # Initialize your step size.
s = ''.join('test string'.split()) # Remove all whitespace from string.
for i in range(len(s)):
    substr.append(s[i: i + step])
# Construct and print a dictionary which counts all occurences of substrings.
occurences = {k: substr.count(k) for k in substr if len(k) == step}
print(occurences)
```

When run, it outputs a dictionary, as you requested:

```
{'te': 1, 'es': 1, 'st': 2, 'ts': 1, 'tr': 1, 'ri': 1, 'in': 1, 'ng': 1}
```

Comment: Hi @hitter, this does indeed work for me, but the string I am concerned with is super large so if i want to print "substr" it crashes my jupiter notebook :D It works better with the counter. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Or do you know what the difference is? I am very new to this topic so please excuse my inexperience.

Comment: Hey @Jonas, I made a slight alteration to the code, now the dictionary is being constructed first, and then gets `print`ed. I was thinking maybe this makes it slightly more efficiently. Let me know if it does, and again thanks for the upvote.